# React Native. Best way for scroll to element inside ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I have scroll view with some component.

```
<ScrollView ref={ref => this.contentRef = ref}>
    <SomeComponent ref={ref => this.targetRef = ref}
</ScrollView>
```

What is the best way for scroll to SomeComponent but limit to ScrollView height?

My try:

```
if (this.contentRef && this.targetRef) {
    const UIManager = NativeModules.UIManager;
    UIManager.measure(findNodeHandle(this.contentRef), (contentX, contentY, contentW, contentH) => {
    UIManager.measure(findNodeHandle(this.targetRef), (activeStepX, activeStepY) => {
        const h = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        if (activeStepY > contentH / 2) {
        this.contentRef.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: h, animated });
        } else {
            this.contentRef.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: contentH, animated });
        };
    });
    });
};
```

But if target very close to screen bottom, I have empty space on bottom (sorry, I need to hide any information).

[image]

But should to look like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like using onLayout method

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout

e.g

```
<ScrollView> 
    <YourComponent onLayout={this.onLayout()} />
</ScrollView>


    onLayout(e) {
      return e.nativeEvent.layout.h // e.g would be the height of your scroll view
    }
```

Comment: I still receive empty area below after I scrolled

Comment: maybe try setting contentContainerStyle prop of ScrollView to {{ flex: 1 }} or {{ height: Dimensions.get("window").height }} or giving Your component some bottomPadding stylying, because ScrollView's prop overScrollMode is already set to 'auto' which allow a user to over-scroll the view only if the content is large enough to meaningfully scroll. hope these  pointers could help helps

Comment: Tried already - no difference. If I scroll by hand - scroll view will return to `normal` view

Comment: @indapublic hey, did you manage to solve the problem in the end?

Comment: I described bug here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22701

Comment: your scroll view height is 812 and position you try to scroll is 1900, so there is definetly something wrong with how you get positions of active elements, or they return some absolute values (here i need to research more)